# ARRAY_AGG function does not work in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I a trying to use ARRAY_AGG function in Spark SQL. When I use it, it throws error

<<Undefined function: 'array_agg'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default>>

```
Dataset<Row> finalDS1 = sparkSession.sql("select array_agg(company_private_id) from TEMP_COMPANY_PRIVATE_VIEW");
```

Anyone know how to solve it? I am trying to compare one array with another column. For that I am using ARRAY_AGG.

```
"select cp.array_column & (select array_agg(int_column) from getCompanyPrivateDS ds1) as filtered_data from getCompanyPrivateDS cp"
```

Comment: postgre native functions don't work within `spark.sql()`. i think [`collect_list()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html#pyspark-sql-functions-collect-list) function does the same here.

Comment: @samkart  I could not use intersection with collect_list method as it is not an array. I want to intersect one array column with the result of array_agg.

Comment: like i said, postgre native methods do not work in spark.sql(). however, it has its own set of methods/functions that can similar things. please read the [function doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html) for more. e.g. intersection can be done using [`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect.html#pyspark-sql-functions-array-intersect)

Comment: @samkart I am trying to use array_intersect. But it shows error <<Undefined function: 'array_intersect'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default>>. I am using spark version 3.3 and java version 8.

Comment: make sure you import the function or the module with an alias.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a documentation error by Spark. They clearly show array_agg() in their function list: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_agg
but I have also experienced that this function doesn't work on Spark 3.1.2

[Collect_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_set)() and [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_list)() should work for your purposes: the former dedupes results, while the latter doesn't.

Comment: Correct, array_agg was added in 3.3.0. There's an issue about this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39582